# Рекурсия в функции в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать постоянно мигающую кнопку в меню. Это возможно вообще сделать на JS, если язык однопоточный?

Есть простейший скрипт, на примере метода `animate()`:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $( "div" ).animate({
        width: "90%", // ширина элемента
        opacity: 0.5, // прозрачность элемента
        height: "150px", // высота элемента
        fontSize: "2em", // размер шрифта элемента
        borderWidth: "5px", // ширина границ элемента
    });
});
```

Подскажите, как реализовать повторение этой функции (зациклить) без перезагрузки страницы?

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Постоянно мигающую кнопку можно сделать вообще без js, на чистом css. Вот самый простой вариант для примера:

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: puls 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes puls {
  0% {background-color: red;}
  100% {background-color: white;}
}
```

```html
<button>Мигающая кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
function loop() {
    $( "div" ).animate({
        width: "90%", // ширина элемента
        opacity: 0.5, // прозрачность элемента
        height: "150px", // высота элемента
        fontSize: "2em", // размер шрифта элемента
        borderWidth: "5px", // ширина границ элемента
    }, {
        // duration: 5000, 
        // easing: 'linear', 
        complete: loop
    });
}

loop();
```

---

Потому что по документации (https://api.jquery.com/animate/) есть такой синтаксис `.animate( properties, options )`. В `properties` данные анимации, а в `options` дополнительные данные (длительность анимации, тип, что сделать по окончании и пр.)

---

```js
function loop() {
    $( "div" ).css({'opacity': 1});
    $( "div" ).animate({
        width: "90%", // ширина элемента
        opacity: 0.5, // прозрачность элемента
        height: "150px", // высота элемента
        fontSize: "2em", // размер шрифта элемента
        borderWidth: "5px", // ширина границ элемента
    }, {
        duration: 500, 
        // easing: 'linear', 
        complete: loop
    });
}

loop();
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Ваш код к сожалению не работает ((

Comment: @КириллНасонов а ошибки в консоли есть какие-нибудь?

Comment: @КириллНасонов добавил кое-что в ответ. оно?

Comment: Да, сейчас работает, спасибо

Comment: @КириллНасонов а вообще, конечно,если надо что-то подобное, то, возможно, лучше на css это сделать, если тот позволяет это сделать полностью.